# German equivalent of "... or ____, rather"?

Tags: culture, interjection, etiquette

My non-native speaker friend has suggested that I use "entschuldigung" less in correcting my misused words when I'm in the middle of a sentence. He says that someone in Germany told him to apologize less, and he sees "entschuldigung" as being too much of an insincere apology, which many German people frown upon.

I argued that one says "excuse me" a lot when correcting a slip of the tongue, but we agreed that being able to say something like "or ___, rather" is less apologetic. (So, for example, saying something like "I went last week to Spandau -- or Potsdam, rather. I get them mixed up, since they're both on the west side of Berlin.")

Is there a commonly used German equivalent that will work for me when I am trying to correct myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ich fuhr gestern nach Hessen, oder genauer, in den Odenwald.

- oder genauer
- oder besser
- beziehungsweise

kommen alle in Betracht.

Potsdam statt Spandau kommt aber nicht in Betracht, weil es disjunkte Mengen sind und das eine keine Präzisierung des anderen, sondern dessen Dementi ist.

Im informellen, mündlichen Gebrauch kommen auch pardon, nein oder falsch in Betracht:

> Ich war gestern in Spandau - pardon - in Potsdam.

> Ich war gestern in Spandau - falsch - in Potsdam.

> Ich war gestern in Spandau, nein, Potsdam.

*Pardon* und *Entschuldigung* sind ja Höflichkeitsfloskeln. Wenn man diese mehrfach, kurz hintereinander nutzt, werden sie zum Ärgernis. Wer ehrlicherweise die Gesprächspartner nicht mit solchen Fehlern, die er sogleich korrigiert, verwirren will, der sollte sich vor dem Sprechen vielleicht etwas mehr konzentrieren oder langsamer sprechen.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the question is in English and the answer in German, so the asker and people searching for it may not be able to understand it without aid. Furthermore, the example *Ich fuhr gestern **nach** Hessen, oder genauer, **den Odenwald*** might be problematic because it features an implied preposition that governs another case (the second part is actually ***in den** Odenwald* instead of ***nach dem** Odenwald*).

Comment: Very informally, one can also use "Quatsch" ("nonsense") or "nein Quatsch", for example: "Ich bin gestern nach Spandau gefahren, Quatsch, nach Potsdam".

Comment: *oder genauer*, *oder besser* and *beziehungsweise* don't describe corrections although they are indeed often used wrongly as such. *oder genauer* und *oder besser* describe specifications. *beziehungsweise* describes some kind of relation between the referred objects. The versions *pardon*, *falsch*, *nein* und *quatsch* do describe corrections.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Wer Deutsch lernen will, der wird meine Antwort verstehen oder an ihr wachsen. Immer wieder kommen derartige  Beschwerden, und ausschließlich von Mutttersprachlern, die offenbar anderen nicht zutrauen, Deutsch zu können oder zu lernen. Wer "Ich fuhr nach Hessen" ohne persönliche, fremde Hilfe nicht entschlüsseln kann, dessen Sprachlücken sind wohl so groß, dass diese Onlinepräsenz das falsche Medium ist, diesen abzuhelfen.

Comment: I find your answer unnecessarily rude.

Comment: @Burki: What do you find rude about it? I read it as very neutral.

Comment: that last sentence sounds quite rude to me. I think that people should be encouraged to speak a language, and not be shamed for making mistakes.

Comment: Ich habe aber niemanden ermuntert, andere für Fehler zu beschämen. Es geht darum, dass jmd. sehr viele Fehler macht, weil er zu schnell spricht, und sich dann laufend entschuldigen muss. Wenn jmd. in der U-Bahn mit dem Rucksack schon 3 Leute angerempelt hat, jeweils "tschuldigung!" gesagt hat, und ungeschickt weiter durch die Menschenmenge rumpelt, dann kaufe ich ihm die Entschuldigung nicht ab. Es ist dann kein Fehler mehr, wie er jedem mal passieren kann, sondern Rücksichtslosigkeit und die Entschuldigunsfloskel ist bloße Fassade. Ich kann aber heucheln, dass es mir nichts ausmacht.

Answer (score 1):

When you say something like "I went last week to Spandau - or Potsdam, rather", then you correct an error.

user unknown has given three perfect versions of saying this in German. However, there is one more variant which I think is most frequently used (perhaps not in an official speech to an audience, but in a *normal* conversation):

> Ich fuhr letzte Woche nach Spandau, **äh**, Potsdam.

The small word **äh** has different meanings depending on the context. Often it is used as a [filler word](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/%C3%A4h) during pauses in speech, though it should be avoided due to stylistical aspects. But it is also used to [correct an error](https://germanistik.uni-wuppertal.de/en/teilfaecher/sprachwissenschaft-des-deutschen.html), especially if you say it with a shake of the head.

Comment: 'äh' should really not be recommended. A lot of people frown upon it, and in every speaker training you learn to avoid it as good as you can.
'nein' (no) would be a much better choice.

Comment: @Burki This is exactly what I wrote in my answer ("it should be avoided due to stylistical aspects"). But nevertheless the use of "äh" is part of linguistic reality and I guess that most people have used it when talking to friends. At least I have ;-) And observe that the question starts with "My non-native speaker friend".

Comment: @Burki Quotation from a [recent article in **Zeit Online**](https://www.zeit.de/2021/26/sicherheitspolitik-deutschland-bundeswehr-carlo-masala): "Und die Deutschen empfinden es als Skandal, wenn sie lesen, dass nichts fliegt, nichts fährt, nichts taucht ... äh, taugt. Aber einsetzen wollen sie diese Bundeswehr nicht. "